# Why does mail create a dead.letter, but the mail still arrives

Tags: solaris, mail-command

When I do this

```
% mail -s "test" me@icloud.com < mail-text
```

it takes a few seconds, then it comes back with this error message:

```
/home/zach/dead.letter... Saved message in /home/zach/dead.letter
```

Still, the recipient (me, in this case) does receive the mail just fine.
I am puzzled by this and would like to send the mail without the error message.

Also, I have just the same line in cron bash script, but I have not seen any error messages or dead.letter's from that.
Any ideas, what might be the difference?

Another funny thing is that if I use mailx instead of mail, everything works just fine.

My Unix is: SunOS login 5.10 Generic_150401-06

Thanks a lot in advance for all kinds of insights or pointers.

PS:
yes, I have already googled, but the only reasons for a dead.letter I have found is when mail could not finish sending, which it does in my case, apparently.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the mail log entries in `/var/log/syslog`? You should find lines with the words '... User unknown'

The default `mail` program does not accept `-s "test"` and therefor treats `"test"` as recipient. The `dead.letter` is saved for the non-mailable recipient called test. Try to add `-t` to the `mail` command to see `"To: test"` appearing in the `dead.letter`.

Finally omit `-s "test"` from your mail command to run it successful without creating/appending to the `dead.letter` file.